# Algebraic multiplicity 1 of the maximal eigenvalue of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When $α_j$ are real numbers positive for each $1 ≤ j ≤ n$ and $λ_{\max}\in \mathbb C $ maximal modulus eigenvalue of matrix A. I.e. $|\lambda_{\max}|=\max \{|\lambda_i|\}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$

We want to set values of $\alpha_j$ with $1 ≤ j ≤ n$ that algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_{\max}$ is $1$.

A= $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \alpha_1 & \alpha_1 & ... & ... & \alpha_1\\ 
  \alpha_2  & 1/2 & \alpha_2 & ... & ... & \alpha_2 \\
  \alpha_3&\alpha_3 & 1/3 & ... & ... & \alpha_3 \\
  \alpha_{n-1} &\alpha_{n-1}&\alpha_{n-1}&...&\frac{1}{n-1}&\alpha_{n-1}\\
  \alpha_{n} &\alpha_{n}&\alpha_{n}&...&\alpha_{n}&\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{pmatrix}$,

What values for $\alpha_j$ i need to take?
Probably it's possible through Matrix Row Operations to get a simple form of this matrix that I can provide her eigenvalues through $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**proof 1**
Since all $\alpha_j$ are positive, and the diagonal is positive, this is a 'positive matrix'.  By **Perron Theory**, the maximal modulus eigenvalue, i.e. the Perron root, $\lambda_1$, is *simple*.  This means $\text{algebraic multiplicity}(\lambda_1)=\text{geometric multiplicity}(\lambda_1)=1$

So any allowed choice for the off diagonal elements will suffice.

**proof 2**
Here's a long way showing that any positive values of $a_i$ will work, this time using real symmetric matrices, for those that don't know Perron Theory.

$A = \mathbf {w1}^T + D$
where $D$ is some diagonal matrix and $\mathbf w$ is a positive vector and $\mathbf 1$ is the vector of all ones

Similarity transforms preserve algebraic and geometric multiplicities so
$\mathbf v:= \mathbf w^\frac{1}{2}$
(where the square root is understood to be taken component-wise)

$\Gamma:= \text{diag}\big(\mathbf v\big)$
$B:= \Gamma^{-1} A \Gamma = \mathbf {vv}^T + D$
i.e. $B$ is real symmetric matrix with positive components which is very nice to work with.  Note: this immediately tells you all eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

now for real symmetric matrices, we know the max modulus eigenvalue is given by
$\max_{\Vert \mathbf x\Vert_2=1}\big \vert \mathbf x^T B \mathbf x\big \vert$
If this eigenvalue was negative that would imply mixed signs for components of $\mathbf x$ and by triangle inequality we'd get an even bigger value with $\mathbf x':=\big\vert \mathbf x\big \vert$ (where absolute value is taken component-wise) which would be a contradiction.  So the max modulus eigenvalue is positive.

We also know that $d_{i,i} \lt \lambda_\max $ i.e. maximal modulus eigenvalue is $\neq$ any of the diagonal elements of $D$.  Using standard basis vectors
$\mathbf e_i^T D\mathbf e_i =d_{i,i}\lt v_i^2 + d_{i,i}= \mathbf e_i^T\big(\mathbf {vv}^T+ D\big)\mathbf e_i $
so $d_{i,i} \lt \max_{\Vert \mathbf x\Vert_2=1}\mathbf x^T B \mathbf x= \max_{\Vert \mathbf x\Vert_2=1}\big \vert\mathbf x^T B \mathbf x\big\vert = \lambda_\max$.  Thus $d_{i,i}\neq   \lambda_\max$

Therefore $\big(D-\lambda_\max I\big)$ is a diagonal matrix with no zeros on the diagonal.
$\implies\text{rank}\big(D-\lambda_\max I\big)=n$

By definition of being an eigenvalue we know
$\text{rank}\big(\mathbf {vv}^T +D-\lambda_\max I\big)\leq n-1$
using rank sub-additivity, i.e. $\text{rank}\big(C+M\big) \leq \text{rank}\big(C\big) + \text{rank}\big(M\big)$
$n=\text{rank}\big(-\mathbf {vv}^T+ (\mathbf {vv}^T +D-\lambda_\max I)\big)$
$\leq \text{rank}\big(-\mathbf {vv}^T\big) +\text{rank}\big(\mathbf {vv}^T +D-\lambda_\max I\big)= 1 + \text{rank}\big(\mathbf {vv}^T +D-\lambda_\max I\big)$
$\implies n-1 \leq \text{rank}\big(\mathbf {vv}^T +D-\lambda_\max I\big)\leq n-1$

hence (by rank-nullity) $\lambda_\max$ has *geometric* multiplicity of $1$.  And since $B$ is real symmetric
*albebraic* multiplicity  = *geometric* multiplicity  $= 1$.

Comment: If it possible through Matrix Row Operations get form of this matrix so that I can provide her eigenvalues?

Comment: row reduction preserves determinants, not eigenvalues so I don't know what you are getting at.